# Convert WebServiceHost to WCF Service Application

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, webservicehost

I have a working console application where all the adresses and configuration are in a config file. But when I try to move this code to a WCF Service Application i get all kinds of errors.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(ImageService));
        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service up");
        Console.ReadLine();

        host.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the WCF service application starts automatically and has no main method, like the console app. How do I define the WCF service to start a WebServiceHost when no main method exists?

Comment: Do you want to self-host this WCF service? When you say your project connects to a Azure Service bus what is it. Are you trying to perform a call to your WCF service that internally calls the Azure Service Bus?

Comment: Im trying to set up a service which could be called from Azure Service bus relay using REST. This works fine with a service initialised like the one above. Of course I dont want to use a console app, which im using now, so I want to convert this to a WCF service hosted on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very easy solution to this problem. In order to tell WCF to use webservice instead, all that is needed is to add this to the .svc file

```
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
```

Somehow I couldent open this file in Visual Studio, so I navigated to the project folder and opened it using notepad. My service .svc-file looks like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyNamespace.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own service by inheriting from the `ServiceBase` class. Override the `OnStart()` method and open your WCF service in the implementation. Override the `OnStop()` method and close your WCF service in the implementation.

Comment: How is this done? I have tried inheriting from ServiceBase and override with OnStart() in the example above, but something more must be added, the OnStart() method is never called

Comment: Create an instance of your service and call OnStart()

Comment: What kind of project to you have now?

Comment: Create an instance? No, I want WCF to be hosted on IIS, so i cant create an instance of my service and call it. How should i create something when there is no main method?

Comment: My project connects a WCF service to azure service bus. When using the console application(with WebServiceHost) and the same config everything works fine. But when using WCF (same config settings) i get "AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher"

Comment: You should maybe add the information that you want to host in IIS to your question. This is quite important. For IIS you have to create a svc file.

Comment: http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp;_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx

Comment: But the problem is not related to IIS. At the moment im deploying it using visual studio. The problem is that I get adress filter mismatch because I cant declare a WebServiceHost in WCF correctly.